# Exception when Parsing String VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Here is the exception:

"Input string was not in a correct format."

Here is the line of code:

```
.Add(Integer.Parse(LoanData.Item("IsApplicantRaceAmericanIndian")).ToString)
```

Comment: We need to see what LoanData.Item() returns before we can help. it's obviously returning a value that Integer.Parse() can't parse.

Comment: Why are you turning the Item into a String, then into an Integer? What is it originally?

Comment: What type is returned from LoanData.Item()?  Is it a boolean?  A string?

Comment: It is throwing because the `LoanData.Item()` returns something that cannot be parsed to an integer. It's kinda obvious.

Comment: What are the contents of LoanData?  What is the value of LoanData.Item("IsApplicantRaceAmericanIndian") ?  Are you guaranteed that it will be an Integer?

Comment: @Ryan, obviously it's not guaranteed thus this question (if this can be called a question because usually those grammar structures end with a question mark and there's not a trace of such thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text you're trying to parse must not represent a valid integer. For example it might be "ABC" or it might be blank.

Use `Integer.TryParse` instead of `Integer.Parse` for a more resilient parsing strategy:

```
Dim text As String = LoanData.Item("IsApplicantRaceAmericanIndian")).ToString()

Dim value As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(text, value)
    .Add(value)
Else
    ' The text could not be parsed. '
    ' Notify the user, log it, do whatever you like. '
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, Integer.Parse won't handle empty or null strings. Try using Integer.TryParse if you are using .NET 2.0 or newer.